# How to open many-tabbed Gnome terminal as one windown instead of many independent windows

Tags: 12.04, bash, gnome-terminal

```
aa=$( ps -e   | grep "chrome" | awk '{print $1;}')
for i in $aa
   do
     gnome-terminal --tab -e" sudo cpulimit -p $i -l 35 " 
   done
```

i want to open one gnome window before the execution of the iteration ,and then use something like `--tab -e ""`, inside the loop to open all in the main gnome window ,and to be all tabbed.In code above, it works but it will open an independent gnome terminal for each iteration of the loop, and i dont want it to be like this

i tried this but it gives me error

```
aa=$( ps -e   | grep "chrome" | awk '{print $1;}')
    gnome-terminal 
for i in $aa
       do
         --tab -e" sudo cpulimit -p $i -l 35 " 
       done
```

Any suggestions ? 
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `--tab` option in gnome-terminal man page. But for example:

```
tab="--tab-with-profile=Default "
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
   do
   foo="$foo $tab"         
   done
gnome-terminal $foo
```

Comment: i get what u want to say , u want to write it the whole command n string variable then execute it all in one gnome terminal below

Comment: nice one :) , although i focused on how to make it with gnome terminal command to make gnome terminal window opened and open tabs in it elsewhere i want but really good one

Comment: Yep. And also you may be interested in terminal multiplexer `tmux` that provides much more flexibility than gnome-terminal tabs.

Comment: by the way do u know where ubuntu save in `etc` the configuration file for `nice -n`

Comment: As I know, there is no configuration file for `nice`.

Comment: maybe but what happened with me is that , i was running a script which there is cpulimit command and i found in terminal suggestion to modify file `.config` located in etc and add line like `* nice -10` i dont remember the path and i want to get it again

Comment: btw there is a problem here if the command i want to execute already contain double quote like this `gnomeTab+="  --tab -e \"cpulimit -p $i -l $limitationPercentage\" " `  
if then i will execute   
`gnome-terminal $gnomeTab` i will get error because it cant parse it well

Comment: so any suggestion to go through it ?